# Apache 2 Listening on Port 9999, but Can't Reach Through DNS Host

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, port-forwarding

I have an Apache server listening on port `9999`.  I can verify this by running an SSH tunnel (with port forward of `L9595 192.168.5.227:9999`) through PuTTY such that from a remote IP I can access this server through the `localhost`:

`localhost:9595`

I have a DNS hostname for my dynamic IP that looks like this:

`server.hostname.org`

And I have a firewall with a rule allowing for traffic through port `9999`.  My problem is I can't access the server here:

`server.hostname.org:9999`

The firewall rule should be correct as I modeled it after other rules that successfully allow traffic.  I can access the main firewall server through:

`https://server.hostname.org`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is Apache httpd bound to the the server's real IP and not just to localhost (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that.  I will look into it.  Thanks.

Comment: It wasn't, so I edited the httpd-vhosts.conf to include but it's still not working...  Not sure.

Comment: Does netstat -an show it listening on the right address now?

Comment: Here is the line from the netstat command: `tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:9999  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN`

Comment: I redid these settings and now I see that `netstat -an` is showing `127.0.0.1:9999` and the `<specific_IP>:9999` in the output.  Still no go from the `server.hostname.org:9999`.  Thanks again so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filing a ticket with the DNS company, I determined that it was not their issue at all. I've been able to successfully configure this to work as desired. Here is what I did:

-Configured Listen port on server
-Confirmed firewall rule
-Started server

Then it was available at `server.hostname.org:9999`

Not sure what was happening but it works now...

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

1. ping server.hostname.org to check if the DNS is correct (or nslookup server.hostname.org)
2. modify apache to listen at port 80 (default)
3. open http://server.hostname.org

If everything works, then change to port 9999 and try to open http://server.hostname.org:9999

Comment: Part of the problem with this idea is that I have something already listening on port 80 (the firewall webGUI); hence, why I need to run this application on another port in the first place.  Plus, I already confirmed the server is running and accessible on port 9999; it's just not when using the DNS hostname.

Comment: I doubt the domain name makes a difference; your results will probably be the same if you manually nslookup to determine your server's IP and use that instead. How is the server hosted? Sounds like you're talking about software firewall on the server itself. But I suspect the traffic is being blocked somewhere between the server and the client. E.g., by the hosting. Open a support ticket with the company you host your server machine with. Ask them to verify whether TCP port 9999 inbound is open to your server.

Comment: The server is hosted by me. I assumed the same as you and that is why I came here.  This seems odd that I can open an ssh tunnel and access the server, but not get it from the DNS hostname.  Perhaps the firewall is not allowing traffic through after all...

Comment: what I was saying was, you tried with the ip address and worked, you try with the DNS name, it didnt work. So, before dealing with ipchains, etc, it's faster and easier to check if there is a misconfiguration with the DNS server, thats why I suggested using nslookup just to check where the problem is

Comment: I tried what you suggested and still got no connection.  I then opened a support ticket with my DNS service.  I suspect they don't allow traffic through other than port 80 with their host names (although not sure why they'd do that).  We'll see...  Thanks for the suggestions.